# Stack DIVs or Table Columns on mobile - HTML and inline CSS only, no stylesheet or media queries

Tags: html, html-table, stack, responsive

this is a bit of an annoying one.

I'm editing HTML blocks on a Moodle site (a bit like editing content on Wordpress, but with no styling options - HTML only!) - it doesn't allow me to add any CSS. Every time I do, it deletes it upon saving my edit.

So... I've been trying for a while (and I'm not great at web coding btw!) to create a standard menu block using either a table or divs. I want them to fit 100% width and then stack when on mobile. Text in each block needs to be responsive as well.

I've been trying with inline CSS, using display:inline-block, but it never works... Don't really udnerstand how the display thing works tbh.

Here's my code so far - apologies, I'm not a coder - did html once decades ago!

Any help, much appreciated. Remember no CSS sheet or Media Queries - pure HTMl and inline CSS only.. Sigh...

```
    <div style=width:100%; height: auto; display:inline-block";>
        <div style="width: 23%; text-align: center; display: inline-block; align: left; background-color: #ffdd00; height: 40px; padding-left:50";>

<h style="width: 25%; height: 35";><a href="https://blabla.com" style="text-decoration: none;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 2vw;">home</span></strong></a></h>
</div>

<div style="width: 25%; text-align: center; display: inline-block; align: left; background-color: #ffdd00; height: 40px; padding-left:50";>

<h style="width: 25%; height: 35";><a href="https://blabla.com" style="text-decoration: none;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 2vw;">home</span></strong></a></h>
</div>

<div style="width: 23%; text-align: center; display: inline-block; align: left; background-color: #ffdd00; height: 40px";>

<h style="width: 23%; height: 35";><a href="https://blabla.com" style="text-decoration: none;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 2vw;">home</span></strong></a></h>
</div>

<div style="width: 23%; text-align: center; display: inline-block; align: left; background-color: #ffdd00; height: 40px";>

<h style="width: 23%; height: 35";><a href="https://blabla.com" style="text-decoration: none;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 2vw;">home</span></strong></a></h>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use <style></style> inside your page? if yes use it add you can apply media queries inside it.

Comment: Hi Adeel - I haven't tried. Also not too familiar with media queries anyway. Would I have to create a <style> tag for every div? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AdeelTahir, no, it's not keeping my <style> tags... Problem is I'm editing small sections within a larger website (learning management system) and the <head> tag, CSS, etc is on the higher site level.

Comment: I am afraid, it seems like there is no solution because it can be done through media queries as you need some ways to display div as inline-block on desktop and show them block on mobile, by making them block those elements will stack themselves but the issue is that you are unable to add even style inside your code.
If you managed to add CSS through some means then you can have solution.

Answer (score 0):

Happy days. Let us get a few things cleared up:

- At this moment you have a container of 100% width, containing a `div` of 23% width, with an `h` that is 23% wide, meaning that `h` is only 23% of 23% wide. I would suggest removing the width of this `h`.
- Also: `<h>` doesn't exist. `<h1>`, `<h2>`... `<h6>` do. Use these, and mark these up accordingly. If that becomes too ugly, only leave the anchor tag with that span inside.
- There are errors in your code. `";>` is an invalid way of closing tags. Use `;">` instead.
- `align:left;` doesn't work in general in the intended way.

To get to answer: while using 23% as a width, that means that you always try to fit these elements at a 23% width inside the container and that will not wrap (it will try cramming them all in). It will, as far as I know, not be possible though to achieve a perfectly responsive result without using media-queries. You can, however try setting a `min-width` in the four divs, with a fixed value, like 320px or so (notice they still need to fit on a mobile device). Then it will *have* to wrap. Additionally, you could play around with `text-align`, `margin:auto`. Bonus: try replacing `display:inline-block` with `float:left;` as that will remove the spaces between the elements. Notice that the markup might fail, and in that case add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` at the bottom of that container-div.

Comment: Thanks for this - it's really helpful!